# Как показать количество всех комментариев только из Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, комментарии

С помощью этого кода, можно вывести количество комментариев со всего сайта:

`<?php 
$comments_count = wp_count_comments(); 
echo $comments_count->approved; 
?>`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вывести сумму всех комментариев только из пост тайпа product? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение таки нашёл:)

```html
<?php 
function get_all_comments_of_post_type($post_type){
  global $wpdb;
  $cc = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(comment_ID)
    FROM $wpdb->comments
    WHERE comment_post_ID in (
      SELECT ID 
      FROM $wpdb->posts 
      WHERE post_type = '$post_type' 
      AND post_status = 'publish')
    AND comment_approved = '1'
  ");
  return $cc;
}
$total_comments =  get_all_comments_of_post_type('product');
 ?>
<div class="reviews_container_amount"><?php echo $total_comments; ?> Reviews</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по анализу кода ядра и кода WooCommerce, этот код будет работать на страницах WooCommerce. WC имеет класс `WC_Comments`, в котором обрабатывается хук ядра `wp_count_comments` и возвращается своё количество комментариев.

Попробуйте просто применить код из вашего вопроса в шаблоне WooCommerce.